# rails isnt seeing proper dir of ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, homebrew

I'm not sure whats wrong but take a look at the picture it says everything i know about the problem

[image]

```
  $ gem install rails 
    Fetching: activesupport-5.0.0.1.gem (100%) ERROR:     
    Error installing rails: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2
```

Comment: You should install RVM, which allows you to use multiple versions of rails. Also, in the future, don't post pictures. Cut and paste the text instead -- it's not that much to ask in exchange for free help.

Comment: sorry, I'm still learning how to use the website and wasn't aware of the etiquette

Comment: have you installed rails in your setup, post the commands you have already executed. execute, $gem install rails and post the o/p here or atleast the success or failure

Comment: $ rails --version

    Rails 5 requires Ruby 2.2.2 or newer.

    You're running
      ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

    Please upgrade to Ruby 2.2.2 or newer to continue.


$ brew install --update ruby
Warning: ruby-2.3.1_2 already installed

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]

$ gem install rails
Fetching: activesupport-5.0.0.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
 activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the ruby version available when rails installation starts is still 2.2.1. 
Even if you upgrade the ruby version, just check the ruby version

```
  $ ruby -v
```

It should still show older one.

You should be using ruby version manager(rvm) to manage different versions of ruby. Using this you can change the default version of ruby so that latest version of rails can be installed properly. In case you want to install some other rails version say 4.2 which is compatible with version of ruby available as default in your system,

```
      $ gem install rails -v=4.2
```

This should install the rails successfully.

Now for better management and as a good practise,
Install rvm,

```
  $ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Now install the version of ruby as required using

```
 $ rvm install 2.3.1
```

Next it make this version as default

```
 $ rvm use 2.3.1 --default
```

just in case you need this version only for a specific project, just use

```
$ rvm use 2.3.1
```

Now check

```
     $ ruby -v
     --2.3.1
```

Fire the rails gem installation now to install.

```
     $ gem install rails
```

This should help